# Bug with the hat "Mmmm bacon"

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2016

Today is the 29th of December. To get `"Mmmm bacon"` you have to `ask, answer, or vote on December 30th`. I got it today even though it isn't the 30th.

Did anyone else get it?

Comment: Damn, I don't want it :E [I'm vegan](https://youtu.be/tRd13bMWhsU?t=54s)

Comment: Too bad you posted something today, because now it's yours

Comment: Found another bug: I got the hat, but I can't taste the bacon.

Comment: Maybe SO can see the future and _knows_ you will ask/answer/vote tomorrow.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

At the time you posted this, it was December 30th already on some Pacific islands, therefore you got the hat. See the following Meta Stack Exchange question:

[Why are date-based hats awarded too early?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159577/why-are-date-based-hats-awarded-too-early/159748#159748)

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288738/295232) for the exact award times for the December 25th hat (Bûche de Noël) – you can extrapolate for the Mmmm Bacon hat.

Comment: So because some islands have it, I get it even though it isn't here yet or in america

Comment: Yes. Don't you love bacon?

Comment: According to the linked post it is +/- 12 hours of the mid day. It is 24 hours until midday tomorrow

Comment: I think you're reading that post the wrong way. It's ±12 hours from mid*night*.

Comment: "we over-awarded the hat so that people in Auckland / Tokyo / Shanghai / Vanuatu wouldn't have to wait until their midday"

Comment: even if it is +- 12 hours from midnight it is a bug because it is 12 hours 22 minutes until midnight

Comment: @LunarWatcher that *would be* the case when the hat was awarded from Dec 30th, 0:00 UTC, which is close to Dec 30th, 12:00 Australian time.

Comment: Some islands are on UTC+14, not UTC+12.

Comment: @LunarWatcher [It's already Friday in Kiritimati](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/)

Comment: So there is a 24 hour span with an additional 48 hours for the last to get out of 30th of december to get the hat?

Comment: The total time span is **50 hours**.

Comment: still ridiculous that it is such a long time for a virtual hat that is erased after this christmas

Comment: @Glorfindel Out of curiosity, what were you testing with your test question? :)

Comment: @Stijn [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340503/wrong-tag-order-for-meta-question).