# Wrong tag order for migrated Meta question

Tags: bug, tags, meta

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340498/mmmm-bacon-hat-bug) (now deleted) has a curious tag order: [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) appears before [support](/questions/tagged/support). Required tags are always displayed first, and tags are sorted by popularity. The tag order was even this way before it was deleted. Any idea what happened here? I could not reproduce it with a [new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340499/this-is-a-test-question) (also deleted).

[image: question with strange tag order]

Comment: Interesting edge case you've found. The question was migrated from [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41379831/revisions) and it had both a *meta* and *support* tag. It looks like tags that exist on MSO are not removed from a migrated question, the system didn't add the default *discussion* tag since it already had one of the mandatory Meta tags, and the tag order was not recalculated but kept from the SO question.

Comment: @Stijn, yes, that could very well be the cause. But that raises another question: why do we have [meta] and [support] tags on the main site?

Comment: [meta] looks like a legit tag, perhaps not the best name. [support] should probably be burninated.

Comment: Just delete all 6 questions with the [support] tag on Main. None of them are worth keeping.

Comment: [[support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support)] is now burninated.

Comment: @Glorfindel the [[meta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta)] tag on the main site is, as it says in its description, related to the `<meta>` element in HTML.