# What happens to the tags when a question is migrated?

Tags: support, tags, migration

I recently found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311393/what-is-difference-between-on-hold-and-closed-questions) which was migrated from the main site to meta. By curiosity, I wondered what happened to the tags when the question got migrated, since the main site and meta have very few (if any) tags in common. So I looked at the [editing history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/311393/revisions) and saw that the question was originally tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) before it was migrated to meta.

How is that possible, since the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag only exists on meta, not on the main site? Was this automatic? Or did the moderator who migrated it intentionally tag it like that? And, more generally, what happens with the tags if a question is migrated to a site which doesn't have the tags that the question has?

By personal experience, I can say that if both sites have the tags that the question was tagged with, the tags don't change, since [one of my questions](https://superuser.com/questions/1149470/why-does-fireftp-disconnect-automatically-after-120-seconds) tagged [firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox) and [ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ftp) was migrated from Stack Overflow to Super User and both sites have both these tags.

But what happens to questions like the other one that are migrated between sites that don't have the same tags?

Comment: The original tags of that migrated question were [stack-overflow] and [question-answering]. Afaik when migrated to meta, they always get replaced with [discussion].

Comment: Maybe they are tagged with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post-mortem)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tags that exist on the target site will be kept; tags that don't exist will be dropped (which can sometimes lead to [strange behaviour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340503/wrong-tag-order-for-migrated-meta-question)).

If a question has no tags in common with the destination site, **the migration will be rejected** unless:

- it is migrated to a Meta site, in which case it will get the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag.
- it was migrated by a moderator, in which case it will get the [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag.
- it uses an [intrinsic tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215921), in which case it will also get the [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag.

Comment: Also worth noting that, unless the migration is to a meta site and/or a moderator is involved, migration will be automatically blocked unless the question contains at least one tag relevant to the target site. (I hope that made sense.) So the only way you could end up with [untagged] is if the question had an "intrinsic" tag, such as a SO question tagged [math] being migrated to [Mathematics.SE].

Comment: Any reference for all this Glorfindel and @Cody, or is this based on your observations?

Comment: Oh, there are plenty o' references over on [the uber-Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) if you care to dig 'em up. Start [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work), @tunaki.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks @Cody.

Comment: 'Twas all lost in the great fire^H^H^H^H meta split