# Winter Bash: why can I wear "Epiphany" on Jan 05?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016, winter-bash

The description for that hat says:

> post or vote on January 6th

As you can see, I am wearing that hat **now**.

And it is January 5th here; and even in UTC is 10.33am 2016-01-05.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Date-based hats are already awarded 14 hours before (and 12 hours after) the UTC date starts/ends. This was the same for other hats in this year's Winter Bash:

- [Mmmm Bacon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340490/bug-with-the-hat-mmmm-bacon)
- [Bûche de Noël](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340257/how-are-some-users-getting-the-b%c3%bbche-de-no%c3%abl-hat-before-december-25th)
- [I Have a Little Dreidel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288738/295232)